# How can I modify a public function inside of the WP_Customize_Manager class?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add another origin source to the output of this WP_Customize_Manager::filter_iframe_security_header class/function.

For my multisite setup with mapped domains, I need to add our (sub)domains to the frame-ancestor sources. If I edit the actual file (/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php) and add the domain, it works as expected. I would like to have this functionality exist in a custom plugin for future upgrades, but I'm having trouble coming up with the correct filter.

Current function:

```
public function filter_iframe_security_headers( $headers ) {
                $headers['X-Frame-Options']         = 'SAMEORIGIN';
                $headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self'";
                return $headers;
        }
```

What I would like to happen:

```
public function filter_iframe_security_headers( $headers ) {
                $headers['X-Frame-Options']         = 'SAMEORIGIN';
                $headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain.com";
                return $headers;
        }
```

What I tried but didn't work:

```
add_filter( 'filter_iframe_security_headers', 'add_iframe_domains' );
function add_iframe_domains( $headers ) {
        $headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN';
        $headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain.com";
        return $headers;
}
```

Class/function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/filter_iframe_security_headers/

Comment: The results of that function are hooked directly to the [`wp_headers`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/8acd96b9bcc5289af65e03433365bd72b662c2db/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#LL1908C16-L1908C26) filter, so you should be able to hook that one later and change it. I think that's about the only way.

Comment: Hm, tried to hook it to wp_headers, but still no go. Wondering if I did it correctly though. Would it just be "add filter('wp_headers', 'add_iframe_domains');"?

Comment: The third parameter to the hook system is the priority, with higher numbers running later, and the default being `10`. Try passing `20` as the second parameter so that your code runs later and overrides the other.

Comment: Woohoo, that was the trick! Thanks @ChrisHaas :)

Comment: I brought all of this into an answer along with a suggestion for a potentially smarter and safer way to run this. If that works for you, and you accept it, we can delete this comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

That specific function doesn't provide any hooks directly unfortunately, however it is [passed directly](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/8acd96b9bcc5289af65e03433365bd72b662c2db/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#LL1908C16-L1908C26) into the common [`wp_headers`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/) with a default priority, so you should be able to just override it with a higher priority such as `20`.

```php
function add_iframe_domains( $headers ) {
        $headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN';
        $headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain.com";
        return $headers;
}
add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_iframe_domains', 20);
```

Doing it just this way, however, means it happens on every page load, both admin and public-facing, which might not be a good idea for security reasons. Instead, you'd ideally hook into an action that is specific to the customizer such as [`customize_preview_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_preview_init/) which is called a [little later](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/8acd96b9bcc5289af65e03433365bd72b662c2db/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#LL1946C3-L1946C48) but in the same function. I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but I would recommend trying this for registering it:

```php
function add_iframe_domains( $headers ) {
        $headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN';
        $headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain.com";
        return $headers;
}

do_action(
    'customize_preview_init',
    static function () {
        add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_iframe_domains', 20);
    }
);
```